# get json objects inside another json object (not array)

Tags: javascript, json, parent, names

i got this structure:

```
{
"parent": {
      "child-parent-1": {
            "att1": null,
            "att2": null,
      },
      "child-parent-2": {
            "att1": null,
            "att2": null,
      }
 }}
```

What i need to get, is the "child-parent-1" and "child-parent-2" names without knowing their names... since they are dynamically generated, like a hash code (askdl1km2lkaskjdnzkj2138).

Tried iterating but i couldn't make it work. I always get the child attributes (key/value pair). Or the entire parent object with all the objects in it. Need to get the parent names i've mentioned above.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for the fast replies!

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterating the object should work:

```
var parents = {
    "parent": {
        "child-parent-1": {
            "att1": null,
            "att2": null,
        },
        "child-parent-2": {
            "att1": null,
            "att2": null,
        }
    }
}

for(var key in parents.parent){       // parents.parent because the children are in a object in `parents`
    console.log(key);                 // child-parent-1 / child-parent-2
    console.log(parents.parent[key]); // The objects themselves.
}
```

For me, this logs:

```
// child-parent-1
// Object {att1: null, att2: null}
// child-parent-2
// Object {att1: null, att2: null}
```

Comment: Yeah, was a dumb question, tried a lot of things but haven't tried that lol. alert(key); made the thing :D